# Question about a hint on approximating a set in outer measure

Tags: real-analysis, probability, measure-theory

This is Exercise 15 from Tao's note: https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2015/10/12/275a-notes-2-product-measures-and-independence/comment-page-2/#comment-682195. Given any subset ${E \subset [0,1]^A}$ (the unit cube, not the set of functions from $A$ to $[0,1]$), we define its outer measure ${\mu^*(E)}$ to be the quantity

$\displaystyle \mu^*(E) := \inf \{ \sum_{i=1}^\infty \mu_0(E_i): E_i \hbox{ open elementary cover of } E \}$,

where $\mu_0$ is the elementary measure, and we say that ${E_1,E_2,\dots}$ is an open elementary cover of ${E}$ if each ${E_i}$ is an open elementary set, and ${E \subset \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty E_i}$.

(Approximation) Show that if ${E \in {\mathcal F}_A}$, then for any ${\varepsilon > 0}$ there exists an elementary set ${E_\varepsilon}$ such that ${\mu^*(E \Delta E_\varepsilon) < \varepsilon}$. (Hint: use the monotone class lemma. When dealing with an increasing sequence of measurable sets ${E_n}$ obeying the required property, approximate these sets by an increasing sequence of elementary sets ${E'_n}$, and use the finite additivity of elementary measure and the fact that bounded monotone sequences converge.)

**Question:** Let $E_n$ be an increasing sequence in ${\mathcal F}_A$ obeying the required property, then for each $n$, we can find an elementary set $E’_n$ with $\mu^*(E_n \Delta E’_n) < \varepsilon/2^n$. Can we select this  approximating sequence $E’_n$ to be increasing as well?